# Problem using mozilla Gecko activex in C# : "The document contains no data"

Tags: c#, mozilla, gecko

I want to use Mozilla Gecko as web browser instead default IE in C#. I had download "Mozilla ActiveX Control v.1.7.12" and add it to Visual Studio toolbox. then drag it to form. when I use navigate method after several seconds I receive this error: "The document contains no data".

I use VS 2010 ultimate and I registered both mozctl.dll and mozctlx.dll using regsvr32

Is there any action which is forgotten?

Comment: Are you sure the URL you are using is valid?

Comment: I use URL like www.google.com and I used IP address also. the default web browser control (IE) works fine with this URL strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

The network which I use has proxy setting.

Go to [Mozilla ActiveX control Installed Directory]\greprefs and open all.js file and edit proxy settings.

Hint: open that .js file with Visual Studio but note pad for avoiding from format confusing.

Thnx everybody.